# Checking whether current time exceeded a time limit

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

For my PHP project I am verifying user emails by mailing them an activation link. On clicking the link which is send along with the email, there email should be verified. This should happen only if the user opens the link within an already set time in admin panel.

I have a table for settings which have the time limit for email verification as:

**id        name         value**

1           email         36000

The time limit(36000) is in seconds. The user email will get verified only if he opens the link within 10 hours after registration. How can I achieve this using Unix timestamp.

Comment: You simply save the timestamp of when the mail was sent, and check whether the timestamp is within the last 10 hours when the user does visit the page...!?!

Answer (score 2):

If you can edit the table. Add a column for sent time. Use unix time and write the time when the mail is sent

Then on registration, take sent time add the value and compare it to mktime().

if its less than mktime then registration will fail, if its greater then registration will be successful.

**Edit**

**id name value Sent_time(bigint)**

1 Email  36000  1387533001

So do your normal sql query and consider we match to row 1 and save it in $row

```
$expire = $row['Sent_time'] + $row['value'];
$now = mktime();
if ($expire  >= $now){
    echo "success expiry time not reached";
} else {
    echo "fail expiry time reached";
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: how can I add the time in seconds (as in table) to the unix timestamp.

Comment: The unix timestamp is in seconds. So simple addition should do the trick, unless i am misunderstanding what you mean?